# How to read TPU consumption during inferencing on edge devices?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, google-coral, edge-tpu

I am running some edge tpu model on edge tpu devices. Is there anyway I can read how much memory from TPU is consuming during the run?

Comment: :))) I didnt mean that, I just let it all caps for attention :(

Comment: sorry for bothering :(

Comment: Your model will consume the same amount of memory each time it is run.  The edgetpu_compiler can give some hints about how much memory you are using:  https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/compiler/#performance-considerations  If your model is too big, it won't fit in the edge TPU all at once, and the performance will suffer, but it can still run.  If your model is much larger, it can be split across multiple edge TPUs by pipelining: https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/pipeline/